# cannot fetch proper id from DB in android

Tags: android, cursor

I fetch a row from DB as a cursor. And then want to get id of it like this:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PEERS + " WHERE " + KEY_NAME + "= '" + peer.name +"'";
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

Log.d("count", c.getCount()+""); // display: count: 1 in LogCat
long peer_id = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_SENDER_ID)); // error occurs in this line;
```

It always display an error:

> Problems receiving packet: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1

and when I change:

`long peer_id = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_SENDER_ID));`

to

`long peer_id = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_SENDER_ID);
 Log.cat("****": peer_id+"");`

LogCat would display `****:0`. However it suppose to display `1`.

Can any one explain what causes the difference and where is wrong in my code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: is KEY_SENDER_ID the id column that you are looking for?

Comment: I think you need to move the cursor once before you get access to the first item: c.moveToNext()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_SENDER_ID);` returns the index of the column `KEY_SENDER_ID` in your `TABLE_PEERS`.

`c.getLong(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_SENDER_ID))` returns the value at Index of the column `KEY_SENDER_ID` in `TABLE_PEERS`.

What you are doing wrong:
You should call `cursor.moveToFirst` before fetching any data from it.

```
Code Snippet:

    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PEERS + " WHERE " + KEY_NAME + "= '" + peer.name +"'";
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (c != null) {    
       if (c.getCount > 0) {
         c.moveToFirst(); 
         Log.d("count", c.getCount()+""); // display: count: 1 in LogCat
         long peer_id = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_SENDER_ID));
       }
    cursor.close();
    }
```

Let me know if it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PEERS + " WHERE " + KEY_NAME + "= '" + peer.name +"'";
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            long peer_id = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_SENDER_ID));
            Log.d("peer_id", peer_id + "");
        }
        cursor.close();
```

You have to use at first moveToFirst() method.